# Selecting IP source address from another interface other than the output one

Tags: c, linux, networking

I would like to know a way by which I can select the IP source address of a packet sent using an UDP socket. I need to send using the IP of the loopback interface lo:0, but the socket automatically fills the source IP with the IP of the output interface.

For example, consider 2 machines which are connected through a vlan with respective interface addressess 10.10.1.1 and 10.10.1.2. The machines loopback addresses are 100.100.100.1 and 100.100.100.2.

Right now, what happens is:

```
     Machine 1                                       Machine 2

           --->  src: 10.10.1.1/dst: 100.100.100.2

                 dst: 100.100.100.2/src: 10.10.10.2 <----
```

I need the following:

```
     Machine 1                                       Machine 2

           --->  src: 100.100.100.1/dst: 100.100.100.2

                 dst: 100.100.100.1/src: 100.100.100.2 <----
```

Does anybody know any solutions to set the outgoing source IP when using the socket ?

I'm programming in C and I'm using Linux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm curious why you "need" to do that?

Comment: Are the machines directly connected or is there a switch/router between them?  If there is a device, what layer is it operating in?

Answer (score 1):

Use `bind()` to specify the local address of the socket.

Be warned that, depending on operating system configuration such as routing rules, this may affect the interface the socket is attached to.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you could always open the socket in raw mode and then you can specify exactly what you want in the IP and UDP Headers, including the source address.

[Raw Sockets Tutorial](http://mixter.void.ru/rawip.html)